# javascript focus not working on load

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.onload = function() {
                 try{

                     document.getElementById('result').focus();
                 }catch(err){

                 }

             }
```

In my form div result id load when form submits and when it show i want to focus on it.
the above code is not working in my case.
Please help me to find problem with this code.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9abhw/)

Comment: Just remove the script tags and use No wrap in <head> instead of onload and use tabindex=0 in the div.

Comment: you are trying to focus on div that you cannot. you can only put focus on any input type field like textbox, radio , checkbox etc.

Comment: why tabindex=0 in div?

Comment: `The focus() method is used to set the focus to a text field.` A div is not a text field....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Here's a working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9abhw/4/)

---

**1.** Give the div a tab index of 0 (meaning it is ordered first):

```
<div class="result" tabindex="0" id="result">
```

(Find out more about the tabindex property [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#tabbing-navigation).)

**2.** Remove your `<script>` tags:

```
window.onload = function() {
    try{
        document.getElementById('result').focus();
    }catch(err){

    }                    
}
```

**3.** Use `no wrap in <head>` instead of `onload`.

Answer (score 2):

According to your jsFiddle, #result is a div.  You can't really focus on a div the way you can with a form element or link, but you can jump to that part of the page using the following javascript instead:

```
window.location.hash = '#result';
```

Comment: Niet problemski.  Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not focus to a div element. But you can use

```
window.location.hash = '#result';
```

to scroll to div#result element

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to focus on a div, which by default can not be put to focus using script. To do that you need to set the [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11) attribute of the result div. You need to add the attribute tabindex and set its value to 0 and then your function `document.getElementById().focus()` will work

Also in your fiddle  is not allowed inside javascript block. Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9GKV3/1/)